# Mongo DB reverse an array field before slicing

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have this mongo query to get the list of messages in a thread.

```
await db
      .collection("threads")
      .find({
        _id: ObjectId(req.query.thread_id),
      })
      .project({
        messages: {
          $slice: [parseInt(req.query.offset), parseInt(req.query.limit)],
        },
        _id: 1,
        date_created: 1,
      })
      .toArray();
```

The limit and offset is set by the client to support unlimited loading. The problem is the query gets result in the order they were added whereas it should paginate with last added messages first. How do I go about this? Is it possible that I can reverse an array before fetching or is it too much load?

This is my thread schema:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f7b32c014014100176c2a55"
   },
   "thread_name":"personal",
   "messages":[
      {
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5f7b32d414014100176c2a56"
         },
         "sender":{
            "$oid":"5f7b329114014100176c2a52"
         },
         "type":"text",
         "date_created":{
            "$date":"2020-10-05T14:51:00.716Z"
         },
         "content":"hi"
      },
      {
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5f7b32df14014100176c2a57"
         },
         "sender":{
            "$oid":"5f7b329114014100176c2a52"
         },
         "type":"text",
         "date_created":{
            "$date":"2020-10-05T14:51:11.302Z"
         },
         "content":"hello"
      },
   ],
   "date_created":{
      "$date":"2020-10-05T14:50:40.271Z"
   },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$reverseArray` option in aggregation

With `aggregate`, you can use first `$match` (it will replace your `find` part), and then, with `$project` you can add new property like `reversedMessages`, where you will use [$reverseArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/) and [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) combined

so, query should be something like this

```js
db.collection("threads").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId(req.query.thread_id),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      date_created: 1,
      reverseMessages: {
        $slice: [
          { $reverseArray: "$messages" },
          0,
          parseInt(req.query.limit), // I guess you want to return latest n messages, where n is a limit from query
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: It's not always the last n messages, in some cases the user scrolls to the end and the next n messages are fetched.

Comment: well, then, you can, instead of `0`, to use as start of slice number of messages that it already loaded (i guess that is `offset`), and then as 2nd param you do `offset + limit`, where I guess limit is number of messages you want to fetch

Comment: For some reason when I run the query I get this: `MongoError: $slice array wrong size` which wasn't coming on the previous query. Any idea why?

Comment: maybe numbers you are providing are out of scope for array?
because, if array is length of 10, and you provide `$slice: [array, 1, 15]`, maybe it will throw you an error?
not really sure
I tested it on some collection that I have, and it was working ok

Comment: I'm starting from 0 basically. Array has length of 25+ and I set the limit to only 5.

Comment: I edited my previous comment, don't know will it help

I was using query like this in my collection 
`db.getCollection('chats').aggregate([{ $match: {_id: ObjectId("5881c8310000000000000000")}},{
    $project: {
        reversedParticipants:  {$slice: [{ $reverseArray: "$participants"}, 1, 2]}}
    }])`
and it was working ok

Comment: Ok, 2nd param is actually how much elements to take, not index. But it should still work in your case

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible that I can reverse an array before fetching?" You can't reverse what you don't have. I've seen the other answer with `$reverseArray` but why spend resources reversing an array when you can just [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) the last elements?

> If negative, $slice returns up to the last n elements in the array. n cannot resolve to a negative number if  is specified

```
db.collection("threads").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId(req.query.thread_id),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      date_created: 1,
      reverseMessages: {
        $slice: [
          "$messages",
          parseInt(req.query.limit) * -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: It's not always I want to get the last n messages, sometimes I want to get the second page from last, at that point how does this work?